# Storing files and folders using android

Tags: java, android, file

I am working on a mobile application where i will save generated values into files. I have stored in file and file is saved in folder as well. But after exiting from application when i open file and try to read values it not reading file. In fact files are storing in device memory not in external device. i have given permissions in manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Here I am attaching my code. Please guide me what mistake i have done.
// here i am storing two data

```
public void setData(String newData , String newTime , String fileName) throws JSONException {
  try { 
  //FileOutputStream fou = openFileOutput("text.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);  
  File sdcard = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  
  File directory = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath()+ "/MyDirectory");  
  directory.mkdirs();  
  File file = new File(directory,fileName);  
  FileOutputStream fou = new FileOutputStream(file , true);  
  OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fou);  
  try {  
  osw.write(String.valueOf(newData));
  osw.append(',');
  osw.write(String.valueOf(newTime));
  osw.write(System.lineSeparator());
  osw.close();  
  } catch (IOException e) {  
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
  e.printStackTrace();  
  }  
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
  e.printStackTrace();  
  }  
  }
```

// Here i am reading file contents which are saved in mobile device

```
  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
  @JavascriptInterface
  public String ReadFile(String fileName)
  {
  String content;
  ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
  //int linenumber = 0;
  File sdcard = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  
  File directory = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath()+ "/MyDirectory");  
  //File directory = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath()+ "/MyDirectory");
  //File f = new File("");
  Log.d(TAG, "acrd checking called");
  System.out.println(sdcard.getAbsolutePath());
  File file = new File(directory,fileName);  
  try (InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
  BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
  //char stringComma = new Character(',');
  while ((content = br.readLine()) != null) {
  // convert to char and display it
  Log.d(TAG, "called");
  arr.add(content);
  Log.d(TAG, "called");
  System.out.println(arr);
  }
  br.close();  
  } 
  catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return arr.toString();
  }
```

What may be problem?

Comment: Any error ? Or the file is just empty ?

Comment: No error. Its storing values and reading from it. But not storing in external device. And If i close application and open it , and if i try to read content its not reading

Answer (score 1):

You should close the `Output stream`, like `fou.close()` after you have finished writing

Answer (score 0):

when use file class often by change File.separator instead / problem solved.
notice, in file and database you need close it when your work is done.

Comment: I dint understand. Can you explain little more?